# Is granting write-only permission on log files to certain users a good practice?

Tags: permissions, security, webserver

Will it be safe to enable logging into a **write-only log file** on a **production server**? I imagine, that this would protect the log file from unwanted eyes. Are there any drawbacks of using this technique?

Comment: See here : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22577/write-access-without-read-access -- you will probably find there what you're looking for.

Comment: @schaiba I've actually seen that question before and haven't found the answer to my question back then. Now, as I scrolled past the accepted answer, I've discovered an answer that talks about the issue I'm interested in. Thanks!

Comment: you should ship your logs to another machine using syslog (rsyslog), so that they don't go missing after a privilege escalation

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan I didn't quite understand what you said. Can you please elaborate on the subject?

Comment: @AlexanderLomia I'm saying you if you're concerned about security then you shouldn't store logs on a production server (making read/write permissions moot) and that you should send them to a logging server using syslog or rsyslog instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logs should be write-only if they contain potentially confidential data. Obviously they can only be write-only to the application that produces the log and other applications running on the server, and perhaps even to the logging subsystem (once written to the log files), but system administrators and auditors should be able to read them.

The most important thing for a log file is integrity. Being write-only doesn't help with integrity. If you can, make the log file append-only (e.g. `chattr +a /path/to/log` under Linux) — but this may not be practical since only root can do this and it needs to be done on each log rotation. Better yet, log on a separate server which does nothing else (and even then, having a non-readable append-only log file does add a bit of redundancy to the security).